# First category set and set-theoretical assumption

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let consider the following set-theoretical assumptions

${A(\mathfrak c)}:$ The union of less than $\mathfrak c$ many first category subsets of $\mathbb R$ is of the first category again.

${B(\mathfrak c)}:$ $\Bbb R$ is not a union of less than $\mathfrak c$ many first category subsets of $\mathbb R.$

It is well known that these conditions follow  from Martin's Axiom. These assumptions are not equivalent.  ${A(\mathfrak c)}$ implies ${B(\mathfrak c)}$ but not the other way around. Is that right?

Comment: It might also be of interest to note that $A(\mathfrak{c})$ is equivalent to the conjunction of $B(\mathfrak{c})$ and the statement that every set of reals of size $<\mathfrak{c}$ is eventually dominated by some real. See for example Theorem 1.2 [here](https://people.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/some.pdf).

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen, Thank you this is very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed.

If $X$ is a family of sets of first category such that $\bigcup X$ is not of first category, then the least cardinality of such a set $X$ is called the *additivity number* of the ideal of first category sets (also called the meagre ideal). If instead we assume that $\bigcup X=\Bbb R$, then the least cardinality of such an $X$ is called the *covering number* of the ideal of first category sets.

I'll write the additivity number as $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal B)$ and the covering number as $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal B)$, where $\mathcal B$ stands for the ideal of first category sets. Then these two cardinalities are [cardinal characteristics of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum), of which it is known that they can be consistently different from both $\aleph_1$ and $\mathfrak c$. They are well-known as being part of [Cichoń's diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram).

To link this to your question, $A(\mathfrak c)$ is the statement that $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal B)=\mathfrak c$ and $B(\mathfrak c)$ is the statement that $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal B)=\mathfrak c$. Since $\Bbb R$ itself is not of first category, we have $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal B)\leq \mathrm{cov}(\mathcal B)$, but it is also consistent that these two cardinals are different.

---

Probably the most elementary models for separating these cardinalities is by using the method of [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)). In particular, if we start with a model of the continuum hypothesis $\aleph_1=\mathfrak c$, and ...

- ... we add $\aleph_2$ many Cohen reals, then this has the effect of making $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal B)=\aleph_1$ and $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal B)=\aleph_2=\mathfrak c$.
- ... we add $\aleph_2$ many random reals, then both cardinals will be equal to $\aleph_1$, while $\mathfrak c=\aleph_2$.

As you note in your question, in a model of Martin's Axiom, both of these cardinals are equal to $\mathfrak c$. This implication does not work in the other direction, since one could use forcing again to get a model where $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal B)=\mathfrak c$ but Martin's Axiom fails, for example by adding Hechler reals.